# Why does my $(document).ready(function()) not get executed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, document-ready

I have  a checkbox on my html view which looks like that:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="hasPrereqBlock" name="hasPrereqBlock" onchange="hasPrereqBlockHandler(this)">
```

And the function that gets triggered by that, looks like that:

```
function hasPrereqBlockHandler(cb){
    if (cb.checked){
        $("#campaignPrereqBlockRevDiv").show();
        $("#instruction_1_RevDiv_M").hide();
        $("#instruction_2_RevDiv").show();
    } else {
        $("#campaignPrereqBlockRevDiv").hide();
        $("#instruction_1_RevDiv_M").show();
        $("#instruction_2_RevDiv").hide();
    }
}
```

When i load the page i want to execute this function and give it a reference to the checkbox, so it displays only the wanted stuff, due to the status of the checkbox, so i have this function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    hasPrereqBlockHandler($("#hasPrereqBlock"));
});
```

I also tried it with document.getElementById("hasPrereqBlock") instead of $("#hasPrereqBlock"), but every of thos 3 elements are shown and they are only hidden when i click the checkbox.
Why does my code not work?

```js
function hasPrereqBlockHandler(cb) {
  if (cb.checked) {
    $("#campaignPrereqBlockRevDiv").show();
    $("#instruction_1_RevDiv_M").hide();
    $("#instruction_2_RevDiv").show();
  } else {
    $("#campaignPrereqBlockRevDiv").hide();
    $("#instruction_1_RevDiv_M").show();
    $("#instruction_2_RevDiv").hide();
  }
}



$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("document ready");
  hasPrereqBlockHandler($("#hasPrereqBlock"));
});
```

```css
#campaignPrereqBlockRevDiv,
#instruction_2_RevDiv {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="hasPrereqBlock" name="hasPrereqBlock" onchange="hasPrereqBlockHandler(this)">

<div id="instruction_1_RevDiv_M">Review 1</div>
<br>
<div id="instruction_2_RevDiv">Review 2</div>
<br>
<div id="campaignPrereqBlockRevDiv">Campaing</div>
```

Comment: Try replacing with `$("#hasPrereqBlock")[0]`

Comment: You need to keep in mind whether you're using vanilla JS or jQuery. `$("#hasPrereqBlock")` is a jQuery object and doesn't have `.checked` (note that your question title is based on a  wrong assumption, always do basic debugging like `console.log("document ready");` to try and narrow down the issue)

Comment: Thank you @ChrisG, that is a good point, "document ready" doesn't get printed, but i don't get why, as jQuery works apart from that..

Comment: That's weird, given that the actual problem is something else. I've edited your snippet and the function is called as expected.

Comment: Ok i added a ```window.addEventListener('load', (event => {});```  and this works allright. But i use ```hasPrereqBlockHandler($("#hasPrereqBlock"));``` which is jQuery, isn't it? So why does jQuery work in this JS-load function but not in a jQuery document ready function?

Answer (score 2):

Your jQuery object has no `.checked`. If you `console.log` `cb.checked` it returns `undefined` instead of a boolean, so you know there is something wrong. `.checked` doesn't exists on a jQuery checkbox object.

Change:

```
cb.checked
```

Into:

```
cb.prop('checked')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that is good to know, but it stil doesn't work..
I think it is some major problem with jQuery itself

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing JavaScript and jQuery! As dcangulo stated, change the element you're sending to the function in the document ready part:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    hasPrereqBlockHandler($("#hasPrereqBlock").get(0));
});
```

`get` returns the element at the given index, and since there is one (you're using an ID, so I assume there is just one) it sends the first. The element sent to the function is the same as the `this` value that gets send when you check the input.

[more information about the get function](https://api.jquery.com/get/)